# dotenv module not working like before in a react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dotenv

I created a new react projet and then I added dotenv.

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

but I got this:

```
{{{

ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 1:11-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\...\project\node_modules\dotenv\lib'


ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 3:13-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\...\project\node_modules\dotenv\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 5:11-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\...\project\node_modules\dotenv\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
}}}
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: I have got the same error but couldn't solve it. Please let me know if u have got it.

Comment: Same error here.  Watching this thread.

Comment: You try install install `dotenv` npm module [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Comment: I have dotenv installed

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1

Install path-browserify, os-browserify and react-app-rewired

```sh
npm install path-browserify os-browserify react-app-rewired
```

### Step 2

In your project root, create `config-overrides.js` file.

In this file, put this.

```js
module.exports = function override (config, env) {
    console.log('override')
    let loaders = config.resolve
    loaders.fallback = {
        // existing configs...
        "fs": false,
        "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
        "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
   }
    
    return config
}
```

### Step 3

**important !**

Change `"start": react-scripts start` in your package.json to `"start": react-app-rewired start`

## Now, restart your project.

```sh
npm start
```

Comment: ok thank you. I will try this. but why things changed ? I don"t use to do this to read env variables

Comment: Did you try ?
Before, react did it automatically. Node.js built-in modules are automatically supported, dotenv needs path and os which are node.js modules.
But now in the new version of react you still have to do this configuration if you want to use a node.js built-in module